# Get the value of tensor in theano

Tags: python, theano

In my program, I want to use the shape value of a tensor. For example, the tensor x has shape of (3,4,5). I want to get the value of 4, i tried the way below:

```
t=x.shape[1] #returns a scalar
t=x.shape[1].eval() #returns a array(4)
```

how can i get a value of 4, what i want is a type of int, not scalar or other types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
import numpy as np
int(np.asscalar(x.shape[1].eval()))
```

Comment: i use x.shape[1].eval()[1] and get 4 at last